# Exact syntax to find and modify (or delete) a matching node in Firebase with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase

I need to loop over my firebase and find a specific record within `/users/{currentUser}/things/` where `thing.feature === "something"`, then modify or delete that node. What is the exact syntax to do that?

I've looked at the docs but find a mix of unhelpful statements like

> When using orderByValue(), children will be ordered by their value.

or that the Return Value for `equalTo()` is

> The generated Query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the later examples in the [Firebase documentation on querying](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries) gives an example of this.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild("height").equalTo(25).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

When applied to your question, it translates to:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://<your-app>.firebaseio.com/user');
var things = ref.child(yourUserId).child('things');
var query = things.orderByChild('feature').equalTo('something');

query.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    console.log('The value of the thing is now: '+JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));

    // We can remove this node with
    // snapshot.ref().remove
    // This will fire a child_removed event

    // We can update this node with
    // snapshot.ref().update({ name: 'Linda H' });
    // This in turn will fire a child_changed event
});
```

As mentioned in the comment, the `child_added` event will fire for both existing child nodes and for nodes that are added after you run the query. Essentially it fires for anything that is new to the query.

Comment: I saw that, tired it and failed. So far as I can tell child_added is a listener for *new* nodes. How do I reference the found node? What kind of object is snapshot. What specific code do I use to get that node returned and work with it (modify or delete)?

Comment: The `child_added` event will fire for any child node that is new to you. So it will fire for both existing and new nodes. I'll update the code to show how to update or delete the node. If that is not clear, can you write a jsfiddle showing your code? That will probably make it easier for me to see what is blocking you.